# Batch command "set /p" won't store user input into a variable

Tags: batch-file, scripting, set

This is the code I'm trying to test. I rounded up that this wouldn't work because When I enter a string, it doesn't output the variable when I echo it (with or without the quotes). I'm just using Notepad++ to write this in, and I'm running it on Windows 8.1.

```
@ECHO OFF

set /p name = Enter a name:
echo "%name%"

pause
exit
```

Exact output when I type in 'Bob':

```
Enter a name:Bob
""
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

with `set /p name =...`, you are defining a variable `%name %`, not `%name%`.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `set /?`. Why wouldn't you have done that.

```
 SET /P variable=[promptString]
```

All your command does is write what you type

You probably have spaces in the set command. `set /p name=whatever`

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't give me what I wanted. Look at the output that is produced, I added it. I know it's a simple program, but that's just because I'm testing one feature.

Comment: You don't seem to pay attention when people tell you things. You assume you know what they are saying when you don't.

Comment: What does that have to do with Batch or coding in general?

Comment: We keep telling you but you won't listen. You didn't define a variable name (your answer was "I did try that"). Now you are using the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@echo off

set /p name=Enter a name:
echo "%name%"

pause
exit
```

Exact output when I type in 'Bob':

```
Enter a name:Bob
"Bob"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Whoops, I did have a variable stored into it, name. I just forgot to add that part when I typed it in on the question. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Twonty2 You sure it doesn't work? for me it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I copied your code directly and the same thing happened. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What did you write the code in?

Comment: My file name is `test.bat`

Comment: Yeah, same. I don't know. It's worked before, it's just not working now.

Comment: AHHH I FIGURED IT OUT. I have the compulsive need to add spaces between my code out of habit developed in C++. I didn't know the string must be touching the '=' operator.

Comment: @Twonty2 yes the spaces makes a difference! :D